# Padding string with 0's -- formatting style?

Tags: c#, string-length

Ok, so I need to pad a string value with a certain number of 0s depending on whether the string is 6 characters in length or not. But the resulting value must be no more than 6 characters.

For example:

- 123 should be changed to 000123
- 4567 should be changed to 004567
- 123456 should not be changed at all

What I have set up right now does not work, unfortunately. It only changed the inputed string value to be D6. (Note: The value of NMFCItemNum can be empty--in those cases, nothing needs to be done).

I have figured out that D# gives the appropriate amount of 0's before a value but the setup is wrong.

```
            string NMFCItemNum = GetValue(curCategory, (int)CategoryCols.NMFCItemNum);
            if (NMFCItemNum != "")
            {
                //Save the value of NMFCItemNum as is
                if (NMFCItemNum.Length == 6)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NMFCItemNumber", GetValue(curCategory, (int)CategoryCols.NMFCItemNum)));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (NMFCItemNum.Length < 6)
                    {
                        //prefix with 0's then save to database
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NMFCItemNumber", String.Format("D6",NMFCItemNum)));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Prix, this wouldn't be a duplicate if the question were about the error with the formatting string. OP, consider re-wording if you still want to use `String.Format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string.PadLeft(Total Width, character)` method

`NMFCItemNum.PadLeft(6, '0');`

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("D6",NMFCItemNum)
```

Has "D6" as a simple string. A formatting string interprets "D6" as just that, "D6". You need to use a *placeholder*:

```
String.Format("{0:D6}", NMFCItemNum);
```

Says "Take the first argument, stuff it into the {0} place, and use "D6" formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string str = "1234"
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(8, '0'));  
//00001234
```